# Maven with Nexus: Creating a zip from the installed artifacts

Tags: java, maven, build, nexus

I am using Maven integrated with Nexus.

I have multiple java projects each creating independent jar files.

1. Should I install the jar's in Nexus Snapshot repository or a regular release repository?
2. How can I bundle all these Jar's into a single zip file after they're all deployed into Nexus?

any help is appreciated

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on what you are releasing: snapshots must be installed into nexus snapshot repository on every build, releases only when you are making an not-snapshot version.
2. There is maven assembly plugin, that can help you with it: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Basically, what is the difference between a snapshot and a release?

Comment: Snapshot is a latest, but non-final build. Artifacts marked as a snapshot must be reloaded from repository on every build (actually they are cached locally for several hours). But non-snapshot artifacts are loaded once and stored in local repo (`$HOME/.m2/repository`) forever

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare the war/jar/ear/rar files you want as a dependency for a new maven project.
2. Use the [maven-assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create a zip